# DLL hell resolution is not working as expected in CLR

Tags: c#, clr, gac, fusion

I am  using two Console applications A1.exe and A2.exe using ClassLibrary version 1.0.0.0 and 2.0.0.0 respectively,i have the respective class libraries installed in GAC as shown in the screen shot but when I run "A1.exe" it fails to find the version 1.0.0.0,the exact error is in the screen shot ,

[image: DLL HELL problem]why is that?how to fix the problem?

Comment: Your screenshots are not useful.  Show the Fuslogvw.exe trace instead.

Comment: Fuslog is not required. Alex's answer below is spot-on

Comment: @HansPassant - how to get the Fuslogvw.exe trace ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are linking to non-strongly-signed assembly. So it can't come from GAC and will try to load local version.

Fix - link to correct assembly.

Comment: if its a non-strongly-signed assembly it wouldn't go to GAC location,it will throw the error  `Failure adding assembly to the cache: Attempt to install an assembly without a strong name`

Comment: @user3682248 the problem is not with the assembly in the GAC (which we all agree must be strong-named), rather that when you are building **a1.exe** and **a2.exe** they are not linking to the strong-named library.  I suspect you are strong-naming as a post build event

Comment: @MickyD - you are right,the linkage was not right,fixed it,thanks all